# Nested scroll view hides action bar in the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-nestedscrollview

My DescriptionActivity.java uses NestedScrollView as the main container. In design view, I can normally see the action bar but when I turn on the emulator, action bar is hidden and the activity is full screen. How can i show action bar also in the emulator?

This is what I see in **design view**:

[image: Screenshot of design tool]

This is what I see in the **emulator**:

[image: Screenshot of emulator]

Here is my **xml code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="przemo.me.recommend.recommendme.DescriptionActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Trailer"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubePlayerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="przemo.me.recommend.recommendme">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CreatorsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DescriptionActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

**Styles:**

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#a8a8a8</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
</style>
```

**DescriptionActvity.java**

```
public class DescriptionActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity
                        implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

TextView filmDesTextView;
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyAniT";
String videoId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

    setTitle("Description");

    filmDesTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filmDesTextView);
    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");

    client.get("https://tastedive.com/api/similar?q=" + title + "&k=movie&info=1", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {

                String description = response.getJSONObject("Similar").getJSONArray("Info").getJSONObject(0).getString("wTeaser");
                final String url = response.getJSONObject("Similar").getJSONArray("Info").getJSONObject(0).getString("yUrl");
                final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=youtu.be/|watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

                if (matcher.find()) {
                    videoId = matcher.group(0);
                }
                filmDesTextView.setText(description);

                youTubePlayerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

                        if(!wasRestored) {
                            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONObject response) {

            Toast.makeText(DescriptionActivity.this, "Data loading failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}
}
```

Comment: Add the screenshot of result.

Comment: Check your manifest. Is your activity's theme extends any **NoActionBar** kind theme?

Comment: I think that manifest is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `YouTubeBaseActivity` extends `Activity` and not `AppCompat`, which is a *beautiful* decision by Google’s clusterfuck of framework.

Unfortunately, short of making your *own* activity for YouTube, the alternative is to use `YouTubePlayerFragment` (see [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)) that won’t care about what Activity it lives on, so your activity can now be a normal `AppCompat` activity, and you do your YT stuff inside the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Can you please update this style in your project !

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

---

Add this code in your main activity.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, it didnt help

Comment: @Przemo Can you please add getSupportActionBar().show(); in your main activity.It may be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: I added this line and still not working, I also added getActionBar().show(); in DescriptionActivity.java but it results in crash: attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Comment: @Przemo Can you please share your java file.

Comment: @Przemo Please add public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity instead of class MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: I just added the code, this activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity becuase it will support displaying videos from youtube

Comment: @Przemo Can you please share gradle file because of I add dependence of YouTube.